# Displaying item from database as checkbox option

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox

how do i display the item from the database into html. I want to display it as a checkbox option. thanks

[image]

Comment: We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write code for you. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

The code below demonstrates how to:

1) Query your database

2) Display it's output in a table with checkboxes beside each entry

3) Submit selected checkboxes to a page

4) Display selection when page reloads

5) Beware of some parameters that you may need to modify, e.g. database name, username, password, name of the primary key ("id").

```
# connect to mysql
$db_link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$db_link)
    die('Cannot connect : ' . mysql_error());

# select database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('test_db', $db_link);
if (!$db_selected)
    die ('Cannot select database : ' . mysql_error());

# execute search query
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `test_table` LIMIT 20';
$result = mysql_query($sql);

# check result
if (!$result)
    die('Could not successfully run query: ' . mysql_error());

# display returned data
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <table style="border: 1px solid black">
        <?php
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                echo '<tr><td>';
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="'.$row['id'].'"/>';
                echo '</td>';
                foreach ($row as $key => $value)
                    echo '<td>'.htmlspecialchars($value).'</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        ?>
    </table>
    <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
    <?php
}
else
    echo '<p>No data</p>';

# free resources
mysql_free_result($result);

# display posted data
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Comment: I think writing code on such a vague question is no good because it is not what SO is all about. Also I wouldnt recommend anyone not using PDO. Source: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-connect.php